# WSO2 EI: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams'

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a data service exposed as a REST resource that inserts data into a MySQL table. When I call this resource directly from postman, it inserts the data successfully. However, when I call it via an endpoint it gives the following error:

```
ERROR {DBInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Error in in-only message receiver DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}


    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:117)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:66)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:358)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:40)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:100)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.executeInOnly(DSOMDataSource.java:78)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:115)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.extractParams(CallQuery.java:337)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:278)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:88)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.resource.Resource.execute(Resource.java:66)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:613)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:94)
    ... 15 more

[2022-07-14 11:13:54,166] ERROR {ServerWorker} - Error processing GET request for : /services/CustomerDataService.HTTPEndpoint/customer/John org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}


    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBUtils.createAxisFault(DBUtils.java:814)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:57)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:100)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.executeInOnly(DSOMDataSource.java:78)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:115)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:66)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:358)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:40)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:52)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:firstName
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: CustomerDataService
Location: /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1657777407345TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/CustomerDataService_1.0.0/CustomerDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getcustomer_firstname
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.extractParams(CallQuery.java:337)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:278)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:88)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.resource.Resource.execute(Resource.java:66)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:613)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:94)
    ... 15 more
```

The endpoint that calls the data service REST resource:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="CreateCustomerInDB" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/CustomerDataService.HTTPEndpoint/customer/{uri.var.firstName}">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </http>
</endpoint>
```

The data service:

```xml
<data name="CustomerDataService" serviceNamespace="" serviceGroup="" transports="">
  <description />
  <config id="CustomerDatasource">
    <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demopresentation</property>
    <property name="username">root</property>
    <property name="password" />
  </config>
  <query id="CreateCustomerEntry" useConfig="CustomerDatasource">
    <sql>insert into customers (FirstName) values (:firstName)</sql>
    <param name="firstName" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN" />
  </query>
   <resource path="customer/{firstName}" method="GET">
      <call-query href="CreateCustomerEntry"          >
         <with-param name="firstName" query-param="firstName" />
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

Point of entry into integration that then calls the above code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/person" name="PersonAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/customer">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Full incoming msg log" level="full" separator=" >>> "/>
            <propertyGroup>
                <property expression="json-eval($.name.first_name)" name="uri.var.firstName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.name.last_name)" name="uri.var.lastName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.date_of_birth)" name="uri.var.dob" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.email)" name="uri.var.email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="TEST" scope="default" type="STRING" value="TEST_VALUE"/>
            </propertyGroup>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.firstName')" name="FName"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.lastName')" name="LName"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.dob')" name="DOB"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.email')" name="Email"/>
                <property expression="get-property('TEST')" name="TESTVAR"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="CreateCustomerInDB"/>
            </call>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all it is a very bad idea to use `GET` for inserting data into database. Just don't do that in that way - the practice does not follow the restfull rules.
And the problem looks like you don't pass `uri.var.firstName` parameter to your endpoint. Question is - how you call this endpoint? Do you have set the:`uri.var.firstName`, before call endpoint for example:

`<property value="TestName" name="uri.var.firstName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

**Update:**

For sending JSON data in POST request to DataService you can follow that documentation: [Data i JSON format](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/data_integration/json-with-data-service/#post-data)
It is important to have proper JSON data structure for that post.

Comment: I am setting `uri.var.firstName` in a property group, and it is getting printed fine, so that should not be an issue. I have updated the question with the API that starts this integration flow.

Comment: also I am aware that POST is the correct way to insert the data, but how would I access the POST data in the SQL query. I could not find a way so I went for GET, knowing that it's an internal call, and the entry point API uses POST anyway. But if there is a way could you please elaborate in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I update answer, and add documentation link. I hope this help, it is quite straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, will go through this. But for the time being, do you know why even if I set `uri.var.firstName` correctly, it still gives the error (using the GET approach)? I have posted the full code in my question.